# How to save new html position after drag and drop?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, local-storage, domparser

I'm working on a project where I have draggable cards that can only be placed within 7 specific placement areas.

I'm able to drag the cards around and place them onto their new areas, but once I reload the page, the positions are not saved.

Upon the "drop" event, I've tried saving the entire new div (the dropped cards new position and the 8 placement areas) that is dynamically created after I "drop" the card, into local storage using "outerHTML" `localstorage.setItem('newCardDashboardDiv', cardDashboard.outerHTML)`, and the data seems to be saved correctly in local storage as a string (i.e. it saves the entire div including the updated inner div that would contain the html elements of the card after it is dragged and placed in any of the placement areas 1 through 7).

I've tried pulling the entire div from local storage data back out and setting it as the new html value `const newDashboardDiv = localstorage.getItem('newCardDashboardDiv)` `$("#cardDashboardDiv).replaceWith(newDashboardDiv)` and it just wont work. I feel like I have tried everything.

Using outerHTML seems like it removes all styling and functional elements of the original HTML once I pull that outerHTML data from local storage. The placement of the new card actually does save upon refresh but it is greyed out and I can no longer drag the card to any new placement area.

I'm using Chrome by the way.

Here is my code

HTML

```
<section id="cardFrameworkDashboard">
<div id="cardDashboardRow" class="container-fluid cardDashboardRow">
  <div id="replaceDash" class="row mt-5">
    <div class="cardPlacementArea" style="width: 30rem; height: 20rem; margin-right: 5rem;">
      <div class="card-body cardContent" draggable="false">
        <h5 class="card-title">System Messages Card</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
        <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="placementArea1" class="cardPlacementArea" style="width: 30rem; height: 20rem; margin-right: 5rem;">
      <div id="droppable1" class="card-body cardContent" draggable="true">
        <h5 class="card-title">Content Card 1</h5>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
        <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="placementArea2" class="cardPlacementArea" style="width: 30rem; height: 20rem; margin-right: 5rem;">
    </div>
    <div id="placementArea3" class="cardPlacementArea" style="width: 30rem; height: 20rem;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row mt-5">
    <div id="placementArea4" class="cardPlacementArea" style="width: 30rem; height: 20rem; margin-right: 5rem;">
    </div>
    <div id="placementArea5" class="cardPlacementArea" style="width: 30rem; height: 20rem; margin-right: 5rem;">
    </div>
    <div id="placementArea6" class="cardPlacementArea" style="width: 30rem; height: 20rem; margin-right: 5rem;">
    </div>
    <div id="placementArea7" class="cardPlacementArea" style="width: 30rem; height: 20rem;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
const cardContentDraggables = document.querySelectorAll('.cardContent')
const cardPlacements = document.querySelectorAll('.cardPlacementArea')
const cardDashboard = document.querySelector('.cardDashboardRow')

cardContentDraggables.forEach(cardContentDraggable => {
    cardContentDraggable.addEventListener("dragstart", () => {
        cardContentDraggable.classList.add("dragging")
    })

    cardContentDraggable.addEventListener("dragend", () => {
        cardContentDraggable.classList.remove("dragging")
    })

    cardPlacements.forEach(cardPlacement => {
        cardPlacement.addEventListener("dragover", event => {
            event.preventDefault()
            const draggable = document.querySelector(".dragging")
            cardPlacement.append(draggable)
        })
        cardPlacement.addEventListener("dragstart", dragStart)
        cardPlacement.addEventListener("dragend", dragEnd)
        cardContentDraggable.addEventListener('drop', () => {
            localStorage.setItem('newCardDashboardDiv', cardDashboard.outerHTML)
            console.log('position saved to ls')
        })
    })
})

function dragStart() {
    for (var i = 0; i < cardPlacements.length; i++) {
        cardPlacements[i].classList.add("cardPlacementAreaDrag")
    }
}

function dragEnd() {
    for (var i = 0; i < cardPlacements.length; i++) {
        cardPlacements[i].classList.remove("cardPlacementAreaDrag")
    }
}
```

JQuery

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    const newDashboardDiv = localStorage.getItem('newCardDashboardDiv')
    console.log('success got div from ls')
    $(window).bind("beforeunload", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault()
      console.log('detected refresh')
    })
    $(window).on('load', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault()
      console.log('after refresh')
      $("#cardDashboardRow").replaceWith(newDashboardDiv)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't work my way through all of your code, but basically the problem is this: After dragging your card, the dom is changed and the page (or parts of it) are re-rendered accordingly.

The moment you reload your page, these changes are gone, as you already said. That makes some sense since the page is completely rendered again, starting at the original source code. Storing the complete div and the dragged items within seems a bit like overdoing it to me, since all you want to do is just some sorting, right?

How about giving your cards something to make them distinguishable, like an ID or a specific (numbered?) class? After dragging you could simply store the position (which area, what position) of every card and "shift" them back into their place after reload …

Comment: I think you're on to something... so let's say I give html card 1 an id="movableCard1". Then, if it gets moved to placementArea3, it will be placed inside the div element of placementArea3. Then how would I store the position of card 1? Based on css styling values?

Comment: That's why I tried to store the entire div into local storage. Because there is no css styling value (for example Top and Left) that I can base off of. It's not free flowing. The card is given the class of "dragging" upon "dragstart" and once a "dragover" occurs over a placementArea, it is appended to that placementArea

Comment: Just find a system to store the position of each card that fits best your needs and your preferences. Like "card1, area5, position3". Put that into an js object and store it into local storage. Write a script that moves your cards into the stored positions. Done ;)